# Import NumPy on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

I'm trying to import NumPy on PyCharm.

Using the PyCharm terminal and Miniconda I've launched the command:

```
conda install numpy
```

And this was the output:

```
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ....................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\...\Miniconda3:
#
numpy                     1.10.4                   py35_0
```

So I run my project but the terminal said:

```
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

On my project bar I can see two different folders, the one with my project and another one with the external libraries.

Under `External libraries` `>` `Extendend definitions` there is a NumPy folder so I guess that the installation goes well.

Comment: You may have multiple installations of Python on your system. Make sure Pycharm uses the correct one: `File -> Settings -> Project {projectname} -> Project Interpreter` The project interpreter should point to the conda installation (`C:\Users\...\Miniconda3`)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Go to

1. ctrl-alt-s
2. click "project:projet name"
3. click project interperter
4. double click pip
5. search numpy from the top bar
6. click on numpy
7. click install package button

if it doesnt work this can help you:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: this probably works, and it is an alternative to the other anwer. In my understanding, this one consists in installing new packages in the current environment rather than setting an existing environment, as in mab's answer.

Comment: For the frustrated people, ctrl-alt-s takes you to File->Settings in windows or PyCharm-> Settings (cmd ,) in mac.

Comment: PyCharm in mac : PyCharm -> Preferences

Answer (score 23):

In PyCharm go to

1. File → Settings, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. < project name > → Project Interpreter → *gear symbol* → Add Local
3. navigate to `C:\Miniconda3\envs\my_env\python.exe`, where *my_env* is the environment you want to use

Alternatively, in step 3 use `C:\Miniconda3\python.exe` if you did not create any further environments (if you never invoked `conda create -n my_env python=3`).

You can get a list of your current environments with `conda info -e` and switch to one of them using `activate my_env`.

Comment: thank you. What would be the motivation for multiple environments? I would guess only people developing their own library would want it, which is a  very small part of the use base.

Comment: You're welcome. Here some scenarios: (1) A library might (still) only be available in Python 2, so one needs a second env for this project. (2) One wants to use PyPy, the much faster Python interpretor, but its current limitations only allow usage in some of ones projects (those which are more pure Python oriented with less C-extension code involved). (3) Testing the latest and greatest new Python 3 version, before fully committing to it, while still keeping ones "old" and working env intact.

Comment: With the recent bug in numpy 1.19.4, you may have to drop down one version to 1.19.3.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that each project may have a separate collection of python libraries in a project specific computing environment. To get this working with `numpy` I went to the terminal at the bottom of the pycharm window and ran `pip install numpy` and once the process finished running the install and indexing my python project was able to import numpy from the line of code `import numpy as np`. It seems you may need to do this for each project you setup in numpy.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered problem installing numpy package to pycharm and finally figured out. I hope it would be helpful for someone having the same problem in installing numpy and other packages on pycharm.

Pycharm Setting :
[image: Pycharm Setting]

Go to File => Setting => Project => Project Interpreter. On this window select the appropriate project interpreter. After this, a list of packages under the selected project interpreter will be shown.
From the list select pip and check if the version column and the latest version column are the same. If different upgrade the version to the latest version by selecting the pip and using the upward triangle sign on the right side of the lists.
Once the upgrading completed successfully, you can now add new packages from the plus sign.

[image]

I hope this would be clear and useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to open the terminal at the pycharm & install it with pip

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `Anaconda3/Library/Bin` to the environment path and PyCharm no longer complained with the error.

Stated by https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001194720/comments/360000341500

Answer (score 0):

In general, the cause of the problem could be the following:

You started a new project with the new virtual environment. So probably you install numpy from the terminal, but it is not in your venv. So

- either install it from PyCahrm Interface: Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Add the package
- or activate your venv and -> pip install numPy